# Continuous maps between compact Hausdorff spaces and their induced maps on their space of continuous real-valued functions.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X,Y$ be two compact Hausdorff spaces and let $ \alpha: X \to Y$ be continuous onto map. Let $\alpha^{*}$ be the induced map from $C(Y)$ to $C(X)$ by mapping any $f \in C(Y)$ to $f \circ \alpha \in C(X)$.

---

First, is it true that the map $\alpha^{*}$ is surjective?

Second, if my first proposition is not always true, then if we substitute "Compact Hausdorff space" with "extremally disconnected compact Hausdorff space", is my first proposition always true? Why?

Thanks.

Comment: $\alpha^*$ will never be surjective unless $\alpha$ is *injective*. Just pick some point $y$ with more than one preimage, and construct a function which is 1 on one of those preimage points and 0 on another: this cannot be the pullback of a function on $Y$.

Comment: And if  $\alpha$ is injective it is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $\alpha[X]$ and we can show that $\alpha^\ast$ is surjective.

Comment: @MikeMiller I was reading an article in American mathematical monthly, in that was said if $\alpha: X  \to Y$ is continuous onto map from an extremally disconnected compact Hausdorff space to a compact Hausdorff space then $\alpha^{*}$ is a norm isomorphism between their space of functions. :-?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $Y$ is a point and $X$ is $S^n$ for example, $f\circ \alpha$ is always constant, there are non constant functions on $S^n$.